# is rails "secret_token" still important with config.session_store(:cache_store)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i've done my google due diligence and can't find an explicit answer. so, good people of stack overflow...

if, in a rails 3 app, i'm not using cookies to store sessions, is it important to securely manage the "Application.config.secret_token"? furthermore, it is used at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The secret_token is used by the cookie_store, used to store session data client side.  [Here](http://robertheaton.com/2013/07/22/how-to-hack-a-rails-app-using-its-secret-token/) is a nice write-up of how to execute arbitrary code using a known secret_token.

This `cookie_store` is more precisely `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`, a rack middleware that rails loads into your rack stack when you set `session_store(:cookie_store)`.  So if you're setting that to `:session_store` you should be fine not setting secret_token.

You can examine `Rails.configuration.middleware` to see all your middlewares and confirm `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` is not one of them.

FWIW, a rails 3.2 app will start with `secret_token` not set, but requests that try to set session variables will fail 500.  I haven't tracked down exactly where the failure happens.

But if you're not setting secret_token, and you don't have `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` in your rack stack, and your app appears to work, you are safe from that particular attack.

The other use of `secret_token` is [digest authentication](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#http-digest-authentication).

In summary, to answer the question, if you're not using digest authentication, and you don't use cookie_store (e.g., by setting `session_store(:cache_store)`), then `secret_token` is not important.

Answer (score 0):

The `Application.config.secret_token` is also used for HTTP Basic and Digest Access Authentication.

[Rais 3.2 HTTP Basic and Digest Access Authentication source file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb)

[Basic and Digest Access Authentication RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)

Comment: "I am not aware" isn't all that helpful.  OP was not aware, hence the question.

Comment: @cluesque, well, thanks to your answer now I am fully aware that secret_token is only used to cookies and digest authentication.
By the way: "and your app appears to work" is as helpful "I am not aware"